# How is It possible to draw 2 merging spherical caps with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to reproduce a figure using only `tikz`. I have produced the figure using `Inkscape` but I am wondering if I can do it fully in Latex.

This is the aimed figure :

[image]

And with the help of some contributors [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696314/merging-2-hemispheres-using-tikz/696482#696482), I was able to reproduce the big lines of the figure by running this code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\tikzset{hemisphere/.style={#1,shading=ball,ball color=#1,fill opacity=0.75}}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}              
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view,rotate around z=-90,line cap=round,line join=round]
  % some dimensions
  \pgfmathsetmacro\r{1}                       % radius
  \pgfmathsetmacro\d{1.9}                     % distance between centers
  \pgfmathsetmacro\a{acos(\d/(2*\r)}          % angle
  \pgfmathsetmacro\jr{sqrt(\r*\r-0.25*\d*\d)} % join radius
  % x-axis and centers
  \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,scale=1.5,fill=gray!7.5] (-\r,-\r) rectangle (\d+\r,\r);
  \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (3.5*\r,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[dashed,-latex] (0,0) -- (0,2.5*\r) node[right] {$y$};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (-2,2*\r)node[right] {$z$} {[canvas is yz plane at x=0]};
  \foreach\i in {0,1}
    \fill (\i*\d,0) circle (0.2mm);
  % left hemisphere
  \draw[black,thin] (225:\r) arc (225:45:\r);
  \draw[hemisphere=blue,scale = 1] (225:\r) arc (225:360-\a:\r)
      {[canvas is yz plane at x=0.5*\d] arc (180:0:\jr)} arc (\a:45:\r) arc (0:180:\r cm);
  % right hemisphere
  \draw[black,thin] (\d,0) ++ (225:\r) arc (225:180+\a:\r)
      {[canvas is yz plane at x=0.5*\d] arc (180:0:\jr)} arc (180-\a:45:\r);
  \draw[hemisphere=green] (\d,0) ++ (225:\r) arc (225:405:\r) arc (0:180:\r cm); 
  \draw[dashed,black,thin]{[canvas is yz plane at x=1.8] (0.05,0) ++ (180:0.95) arc (180:0:0.95)};
        \draw[stealth-stealth,red,ultra thin] (1.9,0,0) -- (1.3,1.05,0.3)node[below right,pos = 0.5,scale = 0.3,red] {$a$} {[canvas is yz plane at x=1.8]};  
            \draw[stealth-stealth,red,ultra thin] (1,0,0) -- (1,0,0.35)node[below right,pos = 0.85,scale = 0.3,red] {$h_0$} {[canvas is yz plane at x=0.5*\d]};  
                          \draw[-latex] (0,0,1.223*\r) -- (-2,2*\r) {[canvas is yz plane at x=0]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Which gives something like this :
[image]

You can notice that is somehow similar but my question is : is it possible to draw something that is not fully spherical ? Much more like a spherical cap rather than a full semi-spherical shape ? I have tried to play with the position of the `xy` plane but I think the problem is with the package `\tikzset{hemisphere}`

Any help/advice would be appreciated !

Thank you in advance,

Best regards.

**UPDATE :**

I tried to follow the same procedure as the post suggested in the comments [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424944/how-can-i-draw-an-spherical-cap-with-an-off-center-hole?rq=1) but didn't manage to do it correctly.
I know that I have to get rid of the `\draw[hemisphere..]` and replace it with another line. My attempt is this but don't work at all :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\tikzset{hemisphere/.style={#1,shading=ball,ball color=#1,fill opacity=0.75}}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}              
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view,rotate around z=-90,line cap=round,line join=round]
  % some dimensions
  \pgfmathsetmacro\r{1}                       % radius
  \pgfmathsetmacro\d{1.9}                     % distance between centers
  \pgfmathsetmacro\a{acos(\d/(2*\r)}          % angle
  \pgfmathsetmacro\jr{sqrt(\r*\r-0.25*\d*\d)} % join radius
  % x-axis and centers
  \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,scale=1.5,fill=gray!7.5] (-\r,-\r) rectangle (\d+\r,\r);
  \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (3.5*\r,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[dashed,-latex] (0,0) -- (0,2.5*\r) node[right] {$y$};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (-2,2*\r)node[right] {$z$} {[canvas is yz plane at x=0]};
  \foreach\i in {0,1}
    \fill (\i*\d,0) circle (0.2mm);
% left hemisphere
\draw[black,thin] (225:\r) arc (225:45:\r);
\shade[ball color=green!50!blue] (0,0) ++ (225:\r) arc (225:0:\r) -- cycle;
% right hemisphere
\draw[black,thin] (\d,0) ++ (225:\r) arc (225:180+\a:\r)
    {[canvas is yz plane at x=0.5*\d] arc (180:0:\jr)} arc (180-\a:45:\r);
\shade[ball color=green!50!blue] (\d+\r,0) arc (0:180:\r) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed,black,thin]{[canvas is yz plane at x=1.8] (0.05,0) ++ (180:0.95) arc (180:0:0.95)};
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,ultra thin] (1.9,0,0) -- (1.3,1.05,0.3) node[below right,pos=0.5,scale=0.3,red] {$a$} {[canvas is yz plane at x=1.8]};  
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,ultra thin] (1,0,0) -- (1,0,0.35) node[below right,pos=0.85,scale=0.3,red] {$h_0$} {[canvas is yz plane at x=0.5*\d]};  
\draw[-latex] (0,0,1.223*\r) -- (-2,2*\r) {[canvas is yz plane at x=0]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424944/how-can-i-draw-an-spherical-cap-with-an-off-center-hole?rq=1

Comment: @jsbibra thank you for your answer : this is indeed the kind of shape I want to have but I tried to do the same operation as the post you shared but didn't manage to succeed : I know for sure I have to modify here :                                    `% left hemisphere
  \draw[black,thin] (225:\r) arc (225:45:\r);
  \draw[hemisphere=blue,scale = 1] (225:\r) arc (225:360-\a:\r)
      {[canvas is yz plane at x=0.5*\d] arc (180:0:\jr)} arc (\a:45:\r) arc (0:180:\r cm);
  % right hemisphere
 ....
  \draw[hemisphere=green] (\d,0) ++ (225:\r) arc (225:405:\r) arc (0:180:\r cm);`

Comment: We already had this question with exactly the same intended drawing here begore ... I don't recall it was yours.

Comment: The only way this is not a duplicate is because you are asking about not full half sphere but a smaller cap. "with the help of some contributors" - name that contributor, as you post his code. Link to that code in the question and accept his answer.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696482/8650

Comment: @hpekristiansen Yes it's not a duplicate as my post is in 2 parts as the post here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591451/draw-arcs-on-spherical-caps-with-fill?rq=1. However, I forgot to link to my previous post which was a mistake. The only reason I didn't accept it as an answer was due to the geometry being different from what I was aiming to get but I thought the answer of this contributor could help others. This motivated my second post. Best regards,

Comment: @MS-SPO Yes you are right : I didn't mention my previous post and it was a mistake. I did it in my updated question. Thank you for noticing that

Comment: Please accept your previous answer